# Limit of $ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2+y^2)\log(x^2+y^2) $?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Can someone help me with this question
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2+y^2)\log(x^2+y^2)
$$
I believe we should be letting $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$, so that $x^2+y^2\Rightarrow r^2$,
and thus the limit would become $\displaystyle{\lim_{r\to0} r^2\log(r^2)}$.

However I am not quite sure of what to do after this step, as the $\log(0)\Rightarrow$ undefined, should I be using the L'Hopital's rule?.

Also, the question asked, if $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, if not, can we make it continuous (and how).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

Apply L'hopital to $$\frac{2\ln(r)}{1/r^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Overkill?

Set $e^{-z} := r^2$, and consider $z \rightarrow \infty.$

Then

$e^{-z} \log (e^{-z}) = \dfrac{-z}{e^z};$

$\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} (- \dfrac{z} {e^z}) =?$

Answer (score 1):

You can use L’Hôpital’s Rule. It’s a limit, not a evaluation. Br careful with that. Also, you can differentiate the natural log.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2+y^2)\log(x^2+y^2)$$
$$L=\lim_{z\to 0}z\log(z)$$
$$L=\lim_{z\to 0}\dfrac {\log(z)}{z^{-1}}$$
Apply l'Hosital's rule:
$$L=\lim_{z\to 0}\dfrac {1}{-z^{-3}}=-\lim_{z\to 0} {z^3}$$
$$ \implies L=0$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, as for the second part of the question, since L=0, does that mean f(x,y) is not continuous at (0,0) then? Since f(0,0) won't be defined right? Also as the questions says, if its possible to make the function continuous, how would we go about doing that. Thanks

Comment: If  the function is define as $f(0;0)=0$   and $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\log(x^2+y^2)$ @Cx330  it will be continuous